# &raquo; in a codeigniter form function

Tags: php, codeigniter

How could i use the entity » inside a form in codeignite php form?

Example:

```
<?php
    echo form_open('pagina/contato');
    echo form_label('Mensagem:', 'mensagem');
    echo form_textarea('mensagem');
    echo form_submit('enviar', 'Enviar mensagem &raquo;', array('class' => 'botao'));
    echo form_close();
?>
```

How do i do to make the entity "»" (&raquo) be printed within the button, in this case instead of the entity name being shown in the button??

Comment: It sounds like CodeIgniter is escaping the content for you so it ends up doing a double-escape. Try using the "»" character literally in your function call `echo form_submit('enviar', 'Enviar mensagem »', array('class' => 'botao'));`

Comment: Ohh my! It actually worked!
Thank you!
Could you answer down there so i can mark it as answered? 
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like CodeIgniter is escaping the content for you so it ends up doing a double-escape. Try using the "»" character literally in your function call:

```
echo form_submit('enviar', 'Enviar mensagem »', array('class' => 'botao'));
```